# Find the previous Monday's date in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, date

How do I check that a specific date is a Monday? Then if it is not a Monday, how do I write a SQL script to give me the date of the previous Monday? For example, if the date (27/2/2024) is a Tuesday, how do I make it show me the date of the previous Monday (i.e. 26/02/2024)?

I tried Google searches and watched some YouTube videos but the only solutions I could find were in SQL Server. However, I'm using SQL Developer/Oracle. I've got as far as being able to detect which day of the week a specific date is:

```
TO_CHAR( TO_DATE( start_date, 'YYYY-MM-DD' ),'DAY' ) AS systart_day_of_week,
```

Thanks!

Comment: Thanks everyone for your help. I tested all suggested solutions and went with Littlefoot's answer in the end. Many thanks for the helpful and speedy responses!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd suggest the `next_day` function.

```
SQL> select next_day(sysdate - 7, 'MONDAY') from dual;

NEXT_DAY(
---------
26-FEB-24

SQL> select next_day(date '2024-02-16' - 7, 'MONDAY') from dual;

NEXT_DAY(
---------
12-FEB-24

SQL>
```

Comment: `select next_day(sysdate - 7, 'MONDAY') from dual;` currently outputs `2024-02-26 21:31:34` it does not change the time component of the date. If you want midnight on Monday you would need `select next_day(TRUNC(sysdate) - 7, 'MONDAY') from dual;`

Answer (score 2):

> How do I check that a specific date is a Monday? Then if it is not a Monday, how do I write a SQL script to give me the date of the previous Monday?

Use `TRUNC(date_value, 'IW')` to truncate the date to the start of the ISO week - which is always midnight on Monday.

```sql
SELECT SYSDATE, TRUNC(SYSDATE, 'IW') FROM DUAL
```

Outputs:

| SYSDATE | TRUNC(SYSDATE,'IW') |
| --- | --- |
| 2024-02-27 21:27:52 | 2024-02-26 00:00:00 |

*Note: `TRUNC(date_value, 'IW')` is independent of the database or sessions language settings; `NEXT_DAY` is not so if someone tries to run `NEXT_DAY(TRUNC(date_value) - 7, 'MONDAY')` when the `NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE` is not `English` then the query will fail with `ORA-01846: not a valid day of the week`.*

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/c5q4CTvW)

Answer (score 0):

...or...  get the number of days between your date and May 2, 1966 (the date the record "Monday, Monday" first hit #1 on the Cash Box 100), find the remainder when you divide by 7, and subtract that many days from your date.

```
mydate - mod(mydate - DATE '1966-05-02',7)
```

Comment: Oracle does not have a `DATEDIFF` function.

Comment: The question is tagged Oracle, which doesn’t have `datediff`.

Comment: edited to remove datediff